# Using dereferenced Vector iterator of type string as function argument

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator, dereference

I am iterating through a vector with

```
std::vector<std::string>::reverse_iterator ritr;
```

I need to at some point find out if a string in this vector is an operator using the function

```
bool IsOperator(const std::string s);
```

When I call the function following way,

```
if(IsOperator(*ritr))
```

eclipse complains!

`Candidates are: 
bool IsOperator(char) 
bool IsOperator(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>)`

(I have an overloaded function with accepts `char` instead of `std::string`)
However, it allows the operation of storing the deferenced iterator in a string

```
std::string str= *ritr;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How does it complain?

Comment: Also, you might consider using references instead of string copies.

Comment: Please show the real code

Comment: You need to post some more code showing the function declaration, how you're creating the iterator etc. If the iterator truly is `std::vector<string>::iterator`, the compiler should have no trouble disambiguating between those two functions. Also, are you saying compilation fails, or is it Eclipse CDT's parser that's showing red squiggles?

Comment: I have specified the function declaration. Yes, it is the Eclipse CDT parser with red squiggles (learnt a new word)

Comment: Could you post a complete program like [this one](http://ideone.com/DPfRAJ) that demonstrates the problem? Also, is the problem just with Eclipse's parser, or does it fail to compile as well?

Comment: The make file compiled the program successfully. It is the eclipse parser! Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Disambiguating between `isOperator(char)` and `isOperator(string)` is not a problem, because a `string` cannot be implicitly converted to a `char`.

I expect your program to compile (if it doesn't, there's something else you are not showing), while the IDE complaining with red squiggles just means that your IDE has a bug.

---

Also, a few remarks:

> I have a function of type `std::vector<std::string>`

A function cannot not have type `std::vector<std::string>`. It can *return* a value of type `std::vector<std::string>`, or it can accept one. I guess you meant the latter.

> `bool IsOperator(const std::string s)`

This function signature doesn't make much sense. You probably meant accepting a constant *reference* to an `std::string` object:

```
bool IsOperator(std::string const& s)
```

Comment: I meant vector type. Sorry. And yes it needs to be const reference. It is a problem with eclipse. Any way to fix it?

Comment: @user592748: I do not use Eclipse, so I don't know unfortunately.

Comment: What do you use, if I may ask?

Comment: @user592748: Mostly notepad :-)